# check if value is present in one of the database rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Im looking for a way to check if a value is present in one of the rows of the page column.

For example if should check if the value '45' is present?

```
 Id | page     |
 ---------------
 1  | 23       |
 ---------------
 2  |          |
 ---------------
 3  | 33,45,55 |
 ---------------
 4  | 45       |
 ---------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function is just what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('45', page) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not store values in lists.  This is especially true in this case:

- Values should be stored in the proper data type.  You are storing numbers as characters.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly defined.
- SQL doesn't have very good string processing functions.
- Resulting queries cannot make use of indexes.
- SQL has a great data type for lists, called a *table*.  In this case, you want a junction table.

Sometimes, you are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  In that case, you can use `find_in_set()` as suggested by Mureinik.